# Internal and External microphones not registering sound

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, and I can't register any audio input. Under the sound settings, my internal speakers are listed, and when I plug in an external microphone, it's also listed, however speaking into either doesn't make the orange bar move. I have tried messing around with `alsamixer` and `pavucontrol` (including unlocking the channels and turning one off), to no avail. I have also tried to use `hdajackretask` in order to set the pin 0x12 to internal microphone (I also tried setting it to pin 0x13). Finally, I have tried removing `alsa-base`, purging, and installing alsa-base, to no avail.

Any advice? Like I said, it seems like we can see the devices, but no audio is registering. I am on a Dell XPS 13 9360.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and the way I solved it was by going into the PulseAudio Volume Control, Configuration tab, and selected the Analog Stereo Duplex profile. The internal microphone started working immediately. For some reason, Analog Stereo Output was selected, which prevented input devices from working. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the configuration was already set to Analog Stereo Duplex.

Comment: I set it to Analog Stereo Duplex but it made not difference.